# Precise definition of valid argument using model theory

Tags: logic, argumentation, validity

In philosophy 101, I learned that a valid argument is any argument that satisfies this property: if all of its premises are true, then its conclusion must hold true.

Now, I am taking a class on metalogic where I learn about first-order model theory. I wonder how the definition of valid argument can be rewritten in a more precise manner in terms of model theory.

One possible way I can rewrite the definition is to first define an argument as a pair: Γ and A, where Γ is a set of sentences (premises) and A is a sentence (conclusion). Then I define an argument (Γ, A) to be valid if and only if for any structure M with M⊨Γ, M⊨A.

I wonder how this precise definition can be put into practice. Consider this simple example of an invalid argument: (Γ, A)=({p→q, q}, p). How can I use the definition to show it is invalid?

I am not sure what is the appropriate first-order language for this context. For now, let's assume that our language L consists two constant symbols: p and q.

In order to show that (Γ, A) is invalid, I can demonstrate with a L-structure M, which has domain {⊤, ⊥} and interpretation: p^M=⊥, q^M=⊤ (I am not sure if symbols ⊤, ⊥ are allowed to be in the domain). With this structure, we have M⊨Γ since M⊨p→q and M⊨q, but M⊨A is false, so (Γ, A) is invalid. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you have it right. In model-theoretic terms, an argument is valid if every model of the premises is a model of the conclusion. In your example, you only need the propositional calculus and you are correct that there is a countermodel when q is true and p is false.

Comment: See [IEP, Model-Theoretic Conceptions of
Logical Consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structure-scientific-theories/#TheStrPerSemVie). However, you do not really need domains if you only consider propositional formulas. Their models just collapse to truth tables, each line of the truth table that assigns ⊤or ⊥ to each propositional letter is a "model". Domains are not for propositional letters but for variables in predicates. Variables run over elements in the domain when the truth of quantified statements is evaluated.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. And yes, you don't need the domains, as Conifold said. And models without domains are called: possible worlds!

Answer (score 1):

@Conifold is correct to say that a model of only propositional formulas is essentially just a truth table. However, if you insist on taking it to the first order level, a standard treatment follows with a multi-sorted logic.

In particular, our vocabular now consists of a set of sorts, with relations of type (sort_1, ..., sort_n). Functions generalize in a similar manner. A structure U is then a family of sets, one for each sort, equipped with an interpretation for each relation symbol R that is interpreted as a subset of Prod_i (sort_i^U). If the arity of R is 0, then Prod_i (sort_i^U) is the empty product, ie a set (by typical set -theoretic considerations) with one element. Call this set {o}. Likewise with functions. In particular, if the relation is of arity zero, it is a subset of {o}, ie either the empty set which we interpret as false or {o} which we interpret as true. In this manner, we can add propositional formulas to our language and give them a semantics. In other words, almost exactly as you have done, but with extra sorts.

see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-many-sorted/ for more.